# How to get remaining time?

Tags: android, timer

I used alarm manager to do a work after a certain minute. But i need to find the remaining time whenever I open that activity.How to do that?

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);                 
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(Timeractivity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
int time = Integer.parseInt(time_et.getText().toString());
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, time);                
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
Toast.makeText(Timeractivity.this, "You set an timer of " + time + " minutes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Get the time the event is scheduled for (e.g. 14:00) and subtract the current time (e.g. 13:20). You should get 0:20 as result.

Comment: give an example code please!

Comment: I would recommend using the examples given in the answers. I just wrote that down, as I haven't had a Compiler at that time to provide a working example.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good way to do a timer, 
i would suggest using a `CountDownTimer`
then on `onTick` u get from that time u know the remaining time, 
and best way in that case to move that data to the activity is using

```
intent.putExtra
```

read more here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: but if app closed then all data will be erased

Comment: @suman the best option for you in this case is to start an IntentService. It runs in a background and automatically stops itself when its done. Perfect match for you. In this service you start CountDownTimer and in onTick() you will send local broadcast messages to your LocalBroadCast receiver. This receiver you will register in your Activity. Don't forget to register it in onStart() and unregister it onStop() (lifecycle methods of your Activity)

Answer (score 1):

```
java.util.Date EndTime; //time from you are calculating remaining
java.util.Date CurrentTime = null; // current time
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
CurrentTime = dateFormat2.parse(dateFormat2.format(new java.util.Date()));
EndTime = dateFormat2.parse(time_in_string);
long remaining_time = EndTime.getTime() - CurrentTime.getTime();//in milliseconds
```

Answer (score 1):

First Choose `SimpleDateFormat` as `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a")` then you need to pass all the required parameters into date format like (year-month-day hour:minute:second AM) i.e (`2021-01-13 5:52:00 AM`). Then simple current time and subrrate current time from endtime.

My code:

```
java.util.Date EndTime; //time from you are calculating remaining
java.util.Date CurrentTime = null; // current time
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");

CurrentTime = dateFormat2.parse(dateFormat2.format(new Date()));

EndTime = dateFormat2.parse(yearSelected + "-" + monthSelected + "-" + (day + 1) + " " + fajrTimeValue + ":00 AM");

long remainingTime = (EndTime.getTime() - CurrentTime.getTime()) / 1000;//in seconds
Log.d(TAG, "startFajrAlert: remainingTime: " + remainingTime);

Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FajrReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + remainingTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Note: If the result from subtraction comes in negative then it's means you have passed a past time in the endTime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Long NexClockTime = alarmManager.getNextAlarmClock().getTriggerTime();
        Long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Long timeLeft = NexClockTime - now;
```

Comment: getNextAlarmClock() was added in API 21

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a timer and override its onTick method. Then you can update your `timeleft` variable in the intervals you want;

Check my complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46012948/2351486